# CSS: Cant set proper width of wrapped inline elements

Tags: html, css

I have two inline elements, an image and an anchor. I want the text in the anchor to wrap depending on a drag bar. My problem is that i want the text to continue in the next line starting under the anchor element and not the image. I can achieve that by specifying the `display: inline-table;` rule. It works great except that now the width of the text goes beyond the width specified, getting hidden by the drag bar:

```
What I want:                              What I get:
                       |                                         |                  
                       |                                         |
|__| This is the anchor|                  |__| This is the anchor|####
     element that needs|                       element that needs|####
     to get wrapped.   |                       et wrapped.       |####
                       |                                         |
                       |                                         |
```

HTML:

```
<div class:"container">
   <img src='someIcon.png'> <a href="">This is the anchor element that
   needs to get wrapped </a> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-table;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

If I disable the `display: inline-table;` I get:

```
                       |                
                       |
|__| This is the anchor|
element that needs to g|
et wrapped.            |
                       |
                       |
```

As so can see, the text is shifted to the right the width of the `<img>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintaining the same HTML structure you can achieve that using `display: inline-flex`.

```css
.container {
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-flex;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <img src='someIcon.png'> <a href="">This is the anchor element that needs to get wrapped </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves the issue.

```css
.container > img {
    float: left;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/340x110"> <a href="#">This is the anchor element that
   needs to get wrapped </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete It is working fine as you can see after running the snippet. Can you please tell me more?